# Swift performSegueWithIdentifier shows black screen

Tags: swift, screen, viewcontroller

I have read through a lot of different posts regarding this issue, but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

I started a new app and I placed the initial ViewController inside a navigation controller. I created a second view and linked them together on the storyboard with a segue. The segue works successfully, and I can see the data I am transferring in a print statement from the second screen, but the screen shows black.

WelcomeScreen:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToTraits"{
        if let gender = self.selectedGender{
            let traitVC = segue.destinationViewController as? TraitViewController
            traitVC!.gender = gender
        }
    }
}

func sendGenderToTraitsView(gender : String?){
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToTraits", sender: self)

}

@IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
    selectedGender = boyGender
    self.sendGenderToTraitsView(selectedGender)
}


@IBAction func button2(sender: UIButton) {
    selectedGender = girlGender
    self.sendGenderToTraitsView(selectedGender)
}
```

Storyboard:
[Link to image of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SPTf.png)
My segue is set as follows:
[Link to image of my segue information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO6dx.png)

Also, my viewControllers are named WelcomeViewController and TraitViewController. They have storyboard id's of welcomeVC and traitsVC.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated. Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: seems ok at first look. Any errors in the debug area?

Comment: when you navigate to the second viewController, does any output logged in the debug area? maybe something like " Failed to instantiate the default view controller"

Comment: [have a look](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=failed+to+instantiate+the+default+view+controller+).

Comment: there isn't any output in the display area, no debug issues pop up. I'll take a look at the search link you sent @vaibhav and see if any of the results match my issue.

Comment: I upvoted the below ans solving your issue, cant you see that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've build your app and everything works, maybe you've missed something, here is my solution **(Note: Code is in Swift 3.0, but should be easy to adopt it to Swift 2.*)**:

**The storyboard:**

[image]

**Set the segueToTraits identifier:**

[image]

**Set the TraitViewController class as custom class in the storyboard:**

[image]

**The view controller with the buttons:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {  

  let boyGender = "boy"
  let girlGender = "girl"
  var selectedGender: String?


  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToTraits"{
      if let gender = self.selectedGender {
        let traitVC = segue.destination as? TraitViewController
        traitVC!.gender = gender
      }
    }
  }

  func sendGenderToTraitsView(gender : String?){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToTraits", sender: self)

  }

  @IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
    selectedGender = boyGender
    self.sendGenderToTraitsView(gender: selectedGender)
  }


  @IBAction func button2(sender: UIButton) {
    selectedGender = girlGender
    self.sendGenderToTraitsView(gender: selectedGender)
  }

}
```

**The trait view controller:**

```
import UIKit

class TraitViewController: UIViewController {


  var gender: String = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("gender: \(gender)")
  }

}
```

**Result:**

[image]

You can find the sample project [here](https://github.com/ronatory/swift-code-examples/tree/master/PerformSequeToSendData)

Comment: you're seriously amazing for going through this in so much detail!! I really appreciate your help. By following your steps I found a stupid mistake I'd made. When I was making the TraitsViewController I must have selected the wrong type of ViewController (it was set to UIPageViewController) and so the segue was taking it to a black screen. Changing it to a regular UIViewController fixed the issue.. man, I feel dumb right now, lol. At any rate, you're completely right!! So I'll mark you answer as correct. Really, thank you again for your help!

Comment: Yeah, glad that I could help you! I think you don't have to feel dumb, these kind of mistakes can happen. So just don't forget, maybe to take a step back and try to walk through the steps slowly again and then you will find mostly in the end the solution ;-)

Answer (score 6):

By following the steps that @ronatory had laid out so well for me in the accepted answer, I was able to see that I had set up my TraitViewController as a UIPageViewController instead of UIViewController.. and so it didn't generate any errors, but it just took me to a black screen. Feel silly that I read through my code so many times and never noticed this.

Main point: If you're getting a black screen on a ViewController randomly, make sure your class is extending the correct parent class.
in my case:

```
class TraitViewController: UIPageViewController {
```

needed to be

```
class TraitViewController: UIViewController {
```