# Firebase - iOs: How to pass data from Tableview to DetailsView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a controller "Feed" which lists multiple posts via a table (a title and image) from Firebase.

[image]

On touch of a button, it brings to a "Feed Details" controller, where I would like the data (title image and caption) from the post clicked previously (parent) being display. (see screenshot 2)

[image]
[image]

At the moment On Click, I just got static information, none of the information are being fetch from Firebase. They are all being called correctly in the main screen, however. So the problem is when it segue to the "DetailsController"

How is it possible to fetch the details from the item click previously ??

Currently this is my feed controller:

```
//
//  Feed.swift
//  MobileAppDemo
//
//  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 31.10.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import SwiftyJSON

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,     UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var addImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleInputView: InputTextView!
@IBOutlet weak var linkbutton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var captionInputView: InputTextView!


private var posts = [Post]()
private var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
private var imageSelected = false

private var readPosts: ObserveTask?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    feedTableView.dataSource = self

    feedTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    feedTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 320

    readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: Post.PROPERTY_CREATED))
    {
        posts in

        self.posts = posts.reversed()
        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
    }



}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell


// here you need to add
{


    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as? MessageCell
    {

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(tableView: tableView, post: post)
        cell.linkbutton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.linkbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedVC.toFeedDetailAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

    }
    else
    {
        fatalError()
    }
}

func toFeedDetailAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let FeedDetailsController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedDetailsController") as! FeedDetailsController
    FeedDetailsController.post = posts[sender.tag]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(FeedDetailsController, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        addImageView.image = image

        imageSelected = true
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func selectImagePressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func postButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    guard let caption = captionInputView.text, !caption.isEmpty else
    {
        // TODO: Inform the user
        print("POST: Caption must be entered")
        return
    }

    guard let title = titleInputView.text, !title.isEmpty else
    {
        // TODO: Inform the user
        print("POST: title must be entered")
        return
    }

    guard let image = addImageView.image, imageSelected else
    {
        print("POST: Image must be selected")
        return
    }

    guard let currentUserId = User.currentUserId else
    {
        print("POST: Can't post before logging in")
        return
    }

    imageSelected = false
    addImageView.image = UIImage(named: "add-image")
    captionInputView.text = nil
    titleInputView.text = nil

    // Uploads the image
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)
    {
        let imageUid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        Storage.REF_POST_IMAGES.child(imageUid).put(imageData, metadata: metadata)
        {
            (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print("STORAGE: Failed to upload image to storage \(error)")
            }

            if let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            {
                // Caches the image for faster display
                Storage.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: downloadURL as NSString)

                print("STORAGE: Successfully uploaded image to storage")
                _ = Post.post(caption: caption, title: title, imageUrl: downloadURL, creatorId: currentUserId)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func signOutButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    // Doesn't listen to posts anymore
    readPosts?.stop()

    try! FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    User.currentUserId = nil
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

and my Feed Details:

```
//
//  FeedDetails.swift
//  MobileAppDemo
//
//  Created by Mikko Hilpinen on 31.10.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikkomario. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import SwiftyJSON

class FeedDetailsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var addImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleInputView: InputTextView!
@IBOutlet weak var linkbutton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var captionInputView: InputTextView!

var post: Post!

private var posts = [Post]()
private var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
private var imageSelected = false

private var readPosts: ObserveTask?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true


    readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: Post.PROPERTY_CREATED))
    {
        posts in

        self.posts = posts.reversed()
    }



}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell


    // here you need to add
{


    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as? MessageCell
    {

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(tableView: tableView, post: post)
        cell.linkbutton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.linkbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedVC.toFeedDetailAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

    }
    else
    {
        fatalError()
    }
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        addImageView.image = image

        imageSelected = true
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func selectImagePressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func postButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    guard let caption = captionInputView.text, !caption.isEmpty else
    {
        // TODO: Inform the user
        print("POST: Caption must be entered")
        return
    }

    guard let title = titleInputView.text, !title.isEmpty else
    {
        // TODO: Inform the user
        print("POST: title must be entered")
        return
    }

    guard let image = addImageView.image, imageSelected else
    {
        print("POST: Image must be selected")
        return
    }

    guard let currentUserId = User.currentUserId else
    {
        print("POST: Can't post before logging in")
        return
    }

    imageSelected = false
    addImageView.image = UIImage(named: "add-image")
    captionInputView.text = nil
    titleInputView.text = nil

    // Uploads the image
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)
    {
        let imageUid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        Storage.REF_POST_IMAGES.child(imageUid).put(imageData, metadata: metadata)
        {
            (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print("STORAGE: Failed to upload image to storage \(error)")
            }

            if let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            {
                // Caches the image for faster display
                Storage.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: downloadURL as NSString)

                print("STORAGE: Successfully uploaded image to storage")
                _ = Post.post(caption: caption, title: title, imageUrl: downloadURL, creatorId: currentUserId)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func signOutButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    // Doesn't listen to posts anymore
    readPosts?.stop()

    try! FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    User.currentUserId = nil
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you as a guide how to use `prepare(for:sender:)` http://stackoverflow.com/a/39930180/5327882

Comment: I can suggest you [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqY5JJptGsc) video. In description there is link where you can download the project and see how to pass data. It is the easiest way but actually I suggest you delegates. But this is the easier way

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `prepare(for:sender:)` in your table view (a `UITableViewDelegate` method) and add the data you need to display to your detail view controller there.

Comment: Hi Mundi,

Thanks,

I'm starting in ios Development, DO you have any example, guide who could help me by any chance ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried using your code but there are so many missing elements that it was returning errors so I don't know if this will compile but it should do.

**First:**

I assume the the `private var posts = [Post]()` in both classes hold the same value of the posts

**Second:**

you need to add `UITableViewDelegate` to your superclass

```
class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ...
```

**Third:**

add the following in your `FeedVC`:

```
private var selectedIndexPath: Int = 0
```

and this in your `FeedDetailsController`

```
var selectedIndexPath: Int = 0 // cannot be private to get accessed from FeedVC
```

and this Delegate function in FeedVC:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
    }
```

and the prepare for segue in FeedVC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let newViewController = segue.destination as! FeedDetailsController

        newViewController.selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
    }
```

Lastly you can now use the `selectedIndexPath` within `posts` to get the chosen post

```
let post = posts[selectedIndexPath]
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Hi Mentos, Thanks for all your time,

I'm trying the following:

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Action" {
            
            let FeedDetailsController = segue.destination as! FeedDetailsController
            
            //  these are the variables you predefined in the class
            
            FeedDetailsController.post = posts
            
        }
    }


But i get an error in FeedDetailsController.post = posts
Saying cannto assign value type [Post] to type 'Post!'

Comment: I also tried             FeedDetailsController.titleInputView = InputTextView!
 instead and I get the same type of error . ..  any idea why ? WIll be amazing, thanks a lot !!

Comment: @tibewww, try `FeedDetailsController.post.insert(<newElement>, at: <Int>)`

Comment: Hmmmmm I'm having '<' is not a prefix unary operator . . . in <newElement>  

I add this code before the last } of the file feed.swift is that fine ?

Comment: @tibewww you need to change <newElement> to the elements that you want to add to your post variable and this needs to be inside your prepare for segue

Comment: hmm anythign I'm trying doesnt seem to work . . . I added post, same error . . .I tried with titleInputView which is  declare in '    @IBOutlet weak var titleInputView: InputTextView!' withotu any sucess as well :( :( i'm desesperate with that to make it work since 3 days :( :(

Comment: @tibewww then use the first option, it is the simplest. If you cannot implement it, I will attempt to add the code myself and post the result but that would be later on in the day

Comment: Thanks Mentos, I'm still trying to make it work but without sucess . . . . if it;s not too much trouble, it will be incredible if you manage to add code yourself !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135095/discussion-between-mentos-and-tibewww).

Comment: @tibewww, check this answer