# Swift - Segue between Views with different titleDisplayMode shows a black bar

Tags: ios, swift, segue, preferslargetitles

When I'm doing a segue between views with largeTitle on in the first and off in the second there is always a black bar while the animation from large to small runs. Is there any way to fix that? Can I change that color?

[image]

Comment: set your UINavigationController instance .view.backgroundColor = .white and this transition will use provided color in this gap

Comment: It works. I didn't found the right color to change. Thanks!

Comment: Please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929877/swift-performseguewithidentifier-shows-black-screen/39930180. This should work!